# WCF Service Fails while Returning SQLConnection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have My Interface as :

```
 [ServiceContract]
    interface IDataRetrieve
    {
        [OperationContract]
        SqlConnection CreateSQLConnection(string connectionString);
        //DataSet GetSQLData(SqlConnection sqlConnection);
    }
```

and the Implementation as:

```
[DataContract]
    public class DataRetriever:IDataRetrieve
    {
        [OperationBehavior]
        public SqlConnection CreateSQLConnection(string connectionString)
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            return connection;
        }
}
```

Now while trying to access the service , getting unaccessible error.

The moment I change the return type of the method as void , service starts working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you want to return SqlConnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlConnection is not serializable so you can't return it from WCF service method. Also it has no sense because you will not be able to connect to sql server from another machine using this connection, you will need to create a new one. If passing a "connection" is a necessity you can pass a connection string and other settings necessary to create a connection.